# Model-specific time zone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a model the represents a Building, and time data for that building should be in the building's own timezone, not the current user's time zone. All timestamps are in UTC. User data should be in his timezone, but the building's should be in its timezone. How would you handle this?

Comment: Please include a code sample or explain what you mean by 'all time data' for your model. What kind of dates/times does this include? How do you determine a building's time zone?

Comment: This might help you: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html